# "Could not find or load main class" OS X M.Lion

Tags: java, macos, runtime-error

I'm having a problem running example code that came with textbook. I"m using `JDK7` on `OS X` Mountain Lion. `StringMutation.java` compiles fine, but running java `StringMutation.class` gives me the following error

`Could not find or load main class StringMutation.class`.

I am running javac StringMutation.java and java StringMutation.class in same directory the StringMutation.java and StringMutation.class are located.

If it matters to know, I have Java SE7 set as the highest priority in Java Preferences.
Thank for any help.

Here is the sample code:

```
public class StringMutation
{

   public static void main (String[] args)
   {
  String phrase = "Change is inevitable";
  String mutation1, mutation2, mutation3, mutation4;

  System.out.println ("Original string: \"" + phrase + "\"");
  System.out.println ("Length of string: " + phrase.length());

  mutation1 = phrase.concat (", except from vending machines.");
  mutation2 = mutation1.toUpperCase();
  mutation3 = mutation2.replace ('E', 'X');
  mutation4 = mutation3.substring (3, 30);

  // Print each mutated string
  System.out.println ("Mutation #1: " + mutation1);
  System.out.println ("Mutation #2: " + mutation2);
  System.out.println ("Mutation #3: " + mutation3);
  System.out.println ("Mutation #4: " + mutation4);

  System.out.println ("Mutated length: " + mutation4.length());
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't include ".class" in the command. You need to run: `java StringMutation`

Answer (score 0):

If you use not empty package you need to run: 
`java <package>.<className>`

*Example: `java com.test.MyClass`*